# Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing when it's my adUnitId from admob

Tags: android-studio, admob, banner

I've got a problem when I load my adUnitId in this code (when it's the adUnitId from admob which said "You are displaying a ...", it's working).
On my phone, on each banner, it's writing required XML attribute "adSize" was missing

```
            AdviewHolder holder= (AdviewHolder) Myholder;
            holder.mAdView = new AdView(mContext);
            holder.mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
            holder.mAdView.setAdUnitId(BANNER_ID);
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)holder.view.findViewById(R.id.Lr);
            layout.addView(holder.mAdView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            holder.mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Ask me if you want more informations
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I've just understand that you can't have the same bANNER_id for multiples banners